# Apache: Redirecting with a case-insensitive path?

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect, case-insensitive

i have the following redirect:

```
RedirectPermanent /SCJ https://fin-iq.com
```

but it does not work for `/scj`, `/sCj`, etc. is there a way to make this case insensitive?

i tried adding [NC,L] but the page crashed.

thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work.

```
RedirectMatch permanent (?i)^/SCJ https://fin-iq.com
```